# Getting the Profile Feed from Google Apps

Tags: python, google-api, google-apps

I am trying to get the profiles feed from my Google Apps domain using the gdata library supplied my Google for Python. This is my code

```
import atom
import gdata.auth
import gdata.contacts
import gdata.contacts.service

gd_client = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsService()
gd_client.email = 'name@domain.com'
gd_client.password = 'password'
gd_client.source = 'madeupgibberish'
gd_client.account_type = 'HOSTED'
gd_client.contact_list = 'domain.com'
gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

def PrintFeed(feed):
  for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
    print '\n%s %s' % (i+1, entry.title.text)

max_results = raw_input(
    'Enter max return: ')
feed_uri = gd_client.GetProfilesFeed()
query = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery(feed_uri)
print(feed_uri)
query.max_results = max_results
#query.orderby='title'
feed = gd_client.GetContactsFeed(query.ToUri())
# Use the print feed method defined above.
PrintFeed(feed)
print(feed_uri)
#print feed

f = open('c:\\python27\\junk.xml', 'w')
f.write(str(feed))
f.close()
```

When I run this it returns:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\gdata-2.0.16>python contactAPI.py
Enter max return: 300
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contactAPI.py", line 27, in <module>
    feed_uri = gd_client.GetProfilesFeed()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\gdata\contacts\service.py", line 294, in GetProfilesFeed
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\gdata\service.py", line 1108, in Get
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 403, 'body': 'Version 1.0 is not supported.', 'reason': 'Forbidden'}
```

I am able to use GetContactsFeed and other feeds, but I cannot get profiles. Any idea whats happening here or what I need to fix? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gdata.contacts.service uses the deprecated version of the API. You should use gdata.contacts.{client, data} instead}
Here is a sample getting users profiles.

```
import atom
import gdata.auth
import gdata.contacts
import gdata.contacts.client
email = 'admin@domain.com'
password = 'password'
domain = 'domain.com'

gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(domain=domain)
gd_client.ClientLogin(email, password, 'madeupgibberish')
def PrintFeed(feed):
  for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
    print '\n%s %s' % (i+1, entry.title.text)

feed_link = atom.data.Link(gd_client.GetFeedUri(kind='profiles'))
while feed_link:
  profiles_feed = gd_client.GetProfilesFeed(uri=feed_link.href)
  PrintFeed(profiles_feed)
  feed_link = profiles_feed.GetNextLink()
```

The [library's](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsamples%2Fcontacts) contact_sample.py and unshare_profiles.py work with the client, data files.

Comment: this worked great, but it only returned 60 entries, I am trying to append max_results to it, but I am still only getting the 60, how do I get the full feed with this method?